# Form inputs get disabled after clicking anywhere on the form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm a beginner dev, please let me know if I missed relevant info.

In my MVC app I have this strange behavior. Form loads and is ready to receive input. As soon as I click the field or anywhere on the form, all the fields are disabled, both dropdowns and inputs. If I manually toggle the modal to show and click cancel or continu, the fields are re-enabled, if I manually toggle to hide, forms are also re-enabled. This was not happening before adding the modal.

**Here is the modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmationModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Veuillez confirmer</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                En cliquant continuer, vous créez un utilisateur pour le client suivant:
                <p>Client ID: <span id="modal-client-id"></span></p>
                <p>Compagnie: <span id="modal-company-name"></span></p>
                <p>Adresse: <span id="modal-address"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="cancelUserCreation()" data-dismiss="modal">Canceller</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirmUserCreation()">Confirmer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the related script**

```
            function showConfirmationModal() {
                debugger;
                function getDivision() {
                    if ($('#divisionBorea').val()) {
                        return 2;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
                var clientId = $('#ClientId').val();
                var division = getDivision();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        clientId: clientId,
                        division: division
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            $('#modal-client-id').text(clientId);
                            $('#modal-company-name').text(response.data.Name);
                            $('#modal-address').text(response.data.Address1);
                            $('#confirmationModal').modal('show');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        toastr['error']('Aucun client trouver avec ce ClientID')
                    }
                })
            }

            const handleSubmit = e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const password = $("#Password").val();
                const passwordValidationResult = validatePassword(password);
                const divisionValidationResult = validateDivisionSelected();

                if (passwordValidationResult) {
                    $("[data-password-hint]").text(passwordValidationResult);
                }
                if (!divisionValidationResult) {
                    $("[data-division-hint]").text("Vous devez choisir une division")
                } else {
                    $("[data-division-hint]").text("")
                }

                if (passwordValidationResult || !divisionValidationResult) {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    showConfirmationModal();
                }
            };
            form.on('submit', handleSubmit);
        });
```

Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

I tried adding hide to the html class but no change
Tried setting the hide attribute in the document.ready function but no change
Tried commenting out parts of the script that disables forms

Commenting out the modal fixes the issue

Comment: They are disabled, as in they have the disabled attribute set on them? When you inspect the form, do you see an event on it?

Comment: No disabled and no event attached either. But I did find the issue in case it helps someone. Even though my modal was hidden and not considered active, it was on top of everything else, hence the appearance of being disabled. Setting the style="display:none" of the modal fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in case it helps anyone. Even though my modal was hidden and not considered active, it was invisible and on top of everything else, hence the appearance of the inputs being disabled. Setting the style="display:none" on the modal fixed it.